# SwiftUI - Is it possible to change an ActionSheet button text after it is displayed?

Tags: swift, swiftui, observable

I would like to show an `ActionSheet` containing InApp purchase objects the user can purchase.

But I want that sheet to contain the prices of such objects, like:

```
Object 1 ($1.99)
Object 2 ($2.99)
...
```

but the price is asynchronous, cause it has to be retrieved from the store.

So, I thought about doing this:

```
  struct Package {
    enum Packtype:String {
    typealias RawValue = String

    case obj1 = "com.example.object1"
    case obj2 = "com.example.object2"
  }

  var productID:String = ""
  @State var namePriceString:String = ""

  init(productID:String) {
    self.productID = productID
  }
}
```

then, when I create the action sheet button I do this:

```
var obj1 = Package(productID: Package.Packtype.obj1.rawValue)
var obj2 = Package(productID: Package.Packtype.obj2.rawValue)

self.getPrices(packages:[obj1, obj2])


let obj1Button = ActionSheet.Button.default(Text(obj1.$namePriceString)) {
  // do something with obj1
}

let obj2Button = ActionSheet.Button.default(Text(obj2.$namePriceString)) {
  // do something with obj1
}

// build the actionsheet
```

later in the code:

```
  func getPrices(packages:[Package]) {
    let productIDS = Set(packages.map {$0.productID})
        
    SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo(productIDS) { (answer) in
      if answer.invalidProductIDs.first != nil { return }
      
      let results = answer.retrievedProducts
      if results.count == 0 { return }
      
      for result in answer {
        if let package = packages.filter({ ($0.productID == result.productIdentifier) }).first {
          package.namePriceString = result.localizedTitle + "(" + "\(result.localizedPrice!)" + ")"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I have an error pointing to `Text` on the button creation lines saying

> Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding' conform to
> 'StringProtocol'

In a nutshell I need this:

1. I display the actionsheet. Its buttons contain no price.
2. I retrieve the prices
3. Actionsheet buttons are updated with the prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to return prices in a `completion` handler and only then display the action sheet:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showActionSheet = false
    @State var localizedPrices = [Package: String]()

    var body: some View {
        Button("Get prices") {
            getPrices(packages: Package.allCases, completion: {
                localizedPrices = $0
                showActionSheet = true
            })
        }
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $showActionSheet) {
            let buttons = localizedPrices.map { package, localizedPrice in
                ActionSheet.Button.default(Text(localizedPrice), action: { buy(package: package) })
            }
            return ActionSheet(title: Text("Title"), message: Text("Message"), buttons: buttons + [.cancel()])
        }
    }
}
```

```
func getPrices(packages: [Package], completion: @escaping ([Package: String]) -> Void) {
    // simulates an asynchronous task, should be replaced with the actual implementation
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
        let localizedPrices = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: packages.map { ($0, "\(Int.random(in: 1 ..< 100))") })
        completion(localizedPrices)
    }
}

func buy(package: Package) {
    print("Buying \(package.rawValue)")
}
```

```
enum Package: String, CaseIterable {
    case obj1 = "com.example.object1"
    case obj2 = "com.example.object2"
}
```

This can be further tuned with loading animations etc...

Comment: ahhh, I see. Excellent idea. Thanks.